# Ajax - how to send parameters from html inputs to service

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, input

I want to send dates from two inputs as parameters to a service. My HTML code:

```
<input type="date" name="dateFrom" value="2016-10-29">
<input type="date" name="dateTo" value="2016-11-29">
<a class="action-button" id="history-report">Generate report</a>
```

For now I have just hardcoded the date values but later they will be chosen from a calendaar.

I want to send the date values together with the request. I have written the following code to send them to a service:

```
$('#history-report').click(
    function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        showLoading()
        const dateFrom = $('input[name="dateFrom"]').val();
        const dateTo = $('input[name="dateTo"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'/params/generate-commission-disposition-report',
            data: {
                dateFrom: dateFrom,
                dateTo: dateTo
            },
            dataType:'json'
        }).done(function(response){
            hideLoading();
            if(response.success === true){
                $('#ajax-success').html(response.msg);
                showSuccess(5000);
            }else{
                showError("Generation error");
            }
        })
        .fail(function(response){
            hideLoading();
            showError("Generation failed")
        });
    }      
);
```

Is the code right solution? At the moment it is not working but I'm not sure whether a mistake is here or in the service I use later.

Comment: Have you used your browser tools to debug your source code? The browser console will tell you if you have an error with javascript, the network tools will display any calls / requests and responses... I would suggest you debug your source code if you haven't already.

Comment: When you say 'not working'... do you get one of your 'Generation Error', or 'Generation Failed' messages? or does nothing show? As NewToJS asks you should post the output in the developer console of a browser if you still can't locate the problem

Comment: In the Chrome console I got '500 (Internal Server Error)'. On FIrefox I got nothing, just the 'failed' message is displayed on the site (defined in the fail method).

Comment: It's just a spelling mistake. You wrote `dataFrom` instead of `dateFrom` (and same for the "to" part)

Comment: @yuvi - You're completely right, shame on me. However, it doesn't change the situation, tit's the same and nothing generated.

Comment: A 500 response indicates a server-side error. What server tech are you using? Probably you need to debug on the server-side and see if that gives you any clues, or post the code here.

Comment: Either than the spelling mistake, there doesn't seem to be a problem with the AJAX (the weird `const` thing aside - what's wrong with `var` for this situation?). If you're getting an error and you need help, *we need to know what the error is*. It might very well be your server side code. In fact, even with the spelling mistake from before, all it would've done is send empty data, not error out. So there's probably a problem with your server-side. Share that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written dataFrom and dataTo instead of dateFrom and dateTo in following two lines. Please change them and it will work:

```
const dateFrom = $('input[name="dateFrom"]').val();
const dateTo = $('input[name="dateTo"]').val();
```

All other things looks fine.

Comment: You're right, but correcting it didn't change much for me, it's still not generating. Anyway, if you say it looks fine beside of that, I will look deeper in how the service works.

Comment: Try to check your request in network tab of debugger, check the parameters of this request does they contain correct values. Also add a breakpoint on your service method and check whether it is getting called or not. !!

Comment: Indeed, the issue relies now only on the service. Thank you!